# Default locale was specified, but _locales subtree is missing

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I started messing around with chrome extensions, trying to build a simple localization extension.
I've added "Default locale" to my manifest, the thing is that I do have a "_locales" dir.

here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "__MSG_appTitle__",
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "default_locale" : "en",
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
      "newtab": "newtab.html"
    }
}
```

Image of my files & dirs (shows _locales folder)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're looking at an old error in chrome://extensions page. Click `clear all` button.

Comment: Hey, sorry but I don't see a "clear all" button anywhere,
can you tell where can I find it? 
thank you :)

Comment: https://puu.sh/HBzBl/86b87617e9.png

Comment: Hey, that is the popup I get:
https://imgur.com/a/tU6W8h2

Comment: Looks like you're loading from the wrong directory instead of `HelloExtension`.

Comment: When I try to load from this dir the message I get is 
"Manifest file is missing or unreadable"
and as you can see I do have a manifest file and I don't understand what's unreadable about it, do you notice something wrong with it?

Comment: It means your manifest.json is in the wrong directory. Move it into HelloExtension and then load from this directory. Alternatively, move the contents of HelloExtension outside.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue it seems your `_locales` directory is under `HelloExtension` directory which is not at the same level of your manifest file, I reproduced the same error using the following structure in my extension[image]

Instead your `_locales` directory should be as follow,
[image]

**N.B:** You can keep the same structure just put your `_locales` at the same level of your `manifest.json`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - [Manifest File](https://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/extensions/manifest.html)

> default_locale
> Specifies the subdirectory of _locales that contains the default strings for this extension. This field is required in extensions that have a _locales directory; it must be absent in extensions that have no _locales directory. For details, see Internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `"default_locale": "en"` worked for me:

```
{
    "name": "__MSG_appTitle__",
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
    }
}
```